# Bootstrap navbar dropdown menu is not working. Logs out the user

Tags: html, jquery, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I am unable to get the dropdown menu working. Whenever I click on the Profile link to drop down and view Account and Logout options it logs me out of my angular app.

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark navbar-fixed-top">
      <a class="navbar-brand text-white" href="#">Brand</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" routerLink="/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" routerLink="/dashboard">Documents</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Profile
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/account">Account</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/account" (click)="authService.SignOut()">Log Out</a>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

**UPDATE**
I know may be missing the sequence of including the .js or .css hence pasting the content of my angular.json & style.css.

**styles.css**

```
@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';  
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
@import "~font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css";
```

**angular.json**

```
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css", 
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
              "src/custom.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js",
              "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
         
            ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction Rory, this snippet works here but I've tried the corrected code as well in my nav component html but it still logs out the user. I don't see any trace in the console. Could this because of the  authguard its throwing out the user ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code snipped above is in pure HTML and Bootstrap. I have run it as you have provided, and it runs as expected. The dropdown works in both [desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KUFM.png)  and [mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BcgJ.png) view. You may want to tweak the coloring of the mobile burger icon, as its invisible, but otherwise functional. I have included some screenshots for your reference.
My best guess is that the issue you're facing has to do with your Angular setup rather than Bootstrap and HTML.

Comment: Issue is resolved. Honestly, I am not sure what fixed it but may be a combination of sequence I was adding in the style.css or angular.json. Thanks everyone